# wrong analog read from arduino

Tags: arduino

I worked project for speed control with potentiometer and measured the speed in percentage on two dc-motor in arduino mega2560.
Pin A0 is for reading value from potentiometer, and managed PWM for motor. Pin A1 must read analog voltage from second motor, and count speed in percentage.
But my pin A1 always reading the same value at the pin A0 although not connected A1.LCD show me a value of variable "display_value" but it is not connected.
Please anyone help me?

```
const int input_1=A0;//input from potentiometer
const int input_2=A1;//input from generator
const int output_enA=10;//PWM, output for H-bridge
//int stanje_senzora=0;
int value_input_1=0;
int value_input_2=0;
int value_output_1=0;
int display_value=0;

//Pins for run dc-motor
int in1 = 8;
int in2 = 9;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(input_1, INPUT);
  pinMode(input_2, INPUT);
  pinMode(output_enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
} 
void motor()
{
  value_input_1=analogRead(input_1);//read analog value from potentiometer
  value_output_1=map(value_input_1, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  //run dc-motor with H-bridge
  digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  analogWrite(output_enA, value_output_1);
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  value_input_2=analogRead(input_2);
  display_value=map( value_input_2, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("speed= "); 
  lcd.print(display_value);
  lcd.print("   %");

  motor();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `A1` unconnected (floating) then it's not able to charge/discharge sampling capacitor from previous measurement, so it looks like the same value. If you connect for example 3.3V, it should measure someting about 66% if 5V `Aref` is used.